# Utilização do SUM() no mysql retornando valor incorreto

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Estou com dificuldades para montar um sql que retorne a soma das entradas e a soma das saidas corretamente. Possuo as tabelas `tbl_produtos(id_produto,NomeProduto)`, `tbl_entradas_produtos(Id_produto,QuantProdutos,Estoque,ExcluirProdutoEnt)`, `tbl_saidas_produtos(Id_produto,QuantProdutos,Estoque,ExcluirProdutoSaida)`

Esse é o sql que estou utilizando:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.NomeProduto, \n"
     . "IFNULL(SUM(ep.QuantProdutos),0) as Entrada, \n"
     . "IFNULL(SUM(sp.QuantProdutos),0) as Saida,\n"
     . "(IFNULL(SUM(ep.QuantProdutos),0) - IFNULL(SUM(sp.QuantProdutos),0)) as Total\n"
     . "FROM tbl_entradas_produtos ep \n"
     . "inner join tbl_produtos p \n"
     . "on (p.idProduto=ep.IdProduto and ep.ExcluirProdutoEnt=0 and ep.Estoque=$IdEstoque) \n"
     . "left join tbl_saidas_produtos as sp \n"
     . "on (sp.IdProduto = p.idProduto and sp.Estoque = $IdEstoque and sp.ExcluirProdutoSaida = 0)\n"
     . "Group by p.NomeProduto";
```

O objetivo desse sql é retornar:

- A 1º coluna com os nomes dos produtos;
- A 2º coluna com a soma da "QuantidadeDeProdutos" de todas as entradas de cada produto;
- A 3º coluna com a soma da "QuantidadeDeProdutos" de todas as saídas de cada produto;
- A 4º coluna com o Total(soma da quantidade de entradas - soma da quantidade de saídas)

Porém ele me retorna alguns registros duplicados, como o exemplo que simulei no meu banco de dados, ele deveria me retornar isso:

```
NOME DO PRODUTO | ENTRADA   | SAIDA | EM ESTOQUE
ALFACE          | 105       | 40    | 65
BANANA          | 50        | 0     | 50 
CENOURA         | 80        | 15    | 65
```

Porém me retorna isso:

```
NOME DO PRODUTO | ENTRADA   | SAIDA | EM ESTOQUE
ALFACE          | 105       | 80    | 25 
BANANA          | 50        | 0     | 50 
CENOURA         | 160       | 30    | 130
```

---

sim, eu simulei com essa query e não consegui nenhuma alternativa para alcançar os valores corretos, isso está ultrapassando meus conhecimentos...
No banco possuo as seguinte linhas que resultam no exemplo do cenário que citei acima...

```
tbl_entradas_produtos:
id | IdProduto | QuantProdutos | Estoque | ExcluirProdutoEnt 
1  | 1         | 75            | 2       | 0
2  | 2         | 75            | 2       | 0
3  | 2         | 30            | 2       | 0
4  | 1         |  5            | 2       | 0
5  | 3         | 50            | 2       | 0

tbl_produtos:
idProduto | NomeProduto
1         | CENOURA
2         | ALFACE
3         | BANANA

tbl_saidas_produtos
id  | IdProduto | QuantProdutos | Estoque | ExcluirProdutoSaida
1   | 1         | 10            | 2       | 0
2   | 2         | 40            | 2       | 0
3   | 1         |  5            | 2       | 0
```

Comment: Pode prover o `DDL` no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Você simulou com essa mesma query com esse left join ?

Comment: Isso acontece pois a quantidade de registros nas tabelas `tbl_entradas_produtos` e `tbl_saidas_produtos` são diferentes. Uma solução viável é usar *subquery:* `SELECT p.idproduto, p.nomeproduto, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(ep.quantprodutos) FROM tbl_entradas_produtos ep WHERE ep.idproduto = p.idproduto AND ep.excluirprodutoent = 0 AND ep.estoque = 2), 0) AS entrada, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sp.quantprodutos) FROM tbl_saidas_produtos sp WHERE sp.idproduto = p.idproduto AND sp.excluirprodutosaida = 0 AND sp.estoque = 2), 0) AS saida FROM tbl_produtos p;`

Comment: Outra que o perguntador some.